# Uploading bytes object to s3 throwing ValueError: Fileobj must implement read

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a base64 string representing a `jpeg` file format but getting `ValueError`.

Code:

```py
with open(base64_txt_file, 'r') as file:
    base64_content = file.read()

img_data = base64_content.encode()
img_content = base64.b64decode(img_data)

print(type(img_content))

object_name = 'sample.jpeg'

client.upload_fileobj(img_content, bucket_name, object_name, ExtraArgs={'ACL': 'public-read'})
```

Output:

```bash
<class 'bytes'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\temp-project\doSpaces-base64-jpeg.py", line 9
    client.upload_fileobj(img_content, bucket_name, object_name, ExtraArgs={'ACL': 'public-read'})
  File "D:\temp-project\venv\lib\site-packages\boto3\s3\inject.py", line 618, in upload_fileobj
    raise ValueError('Fileobj must implement read')
ValueError: Fileobj must implement read
```

I aim to upload a `base64` format file to the s3 bucket and get a public URL. Please note that I do not want to store the file locally, so I am relying on the `base64` string since I expect this string to be received from the API directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name and [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/upload_fileobj.html) indicates, `upload_fileobj` is for file-like objects and not just regular bytes:

> Fileobj (a file-like object) – A file-like object to upload. At a minimum, **it must implement the read method**, and must return bytes.

Use [`putObject`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/put_object.html) instead, which supports bytes:

> Body (**bytes** or seekable file-like object) – Object data.

```py
with open(base64_txt_file, 'r') as file:
    base64_content = file.read()

img_data = base64_content.encode()
img_content = base64.b64decode(img_data)

object_name = 'sample.jpeg'

client.put_object(Body=img_content, Bucket=bucket_name,
                  Key=object_name, ACL='public-read')
```

Comment: It says `Access Denied`. I am able to access the link by saving it locally and then uploading it using the `upload_file()` method.

Comment: I need the full error to help, but that'll be IAM related most likely.

Comment: Trying to access [this public URL](https://stringlab-spaces.blr1.digitaloceanspaces.com/edtech/abc.jpeg) throws this error: AccessDeniedstringlab-spacestx0000004b856683180788d-00651a4ced-2015df-blr1a2015df-blr1a-blr1-zg01

Comment: Something is wrong with your config; check the object permissions and the bucket config.